# When is a planar embedding unique?

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science

I couldn't find any answer to this question in my script.  [This planar graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVD07.png) is considerd to be unique and [this one don't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRb58.png). 
Has this something to do with the cyclic orders of edges?

Comment: What's your (formal) definition of "unique"?

Comment: [It is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_embedding#Combinatorial_embedding)

Comment: Thank you @noodlesGroup I stumbled over that myself, but I was not sure, if I was correct (my english skills are not the best :-) thx again!

Comment: 3-connected planar graphs have unique embeddings: that's a theorem of Whitney. If you can disconnected a planar graph by removing two vertices, then you can clearly produce two different embeddings (by picking one of the components you get that way and "flipping" it)

Comment: A statement and proof of this theorem can be found on slide 22 of [this presentation](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~culler/talks/planargraphs.pdf).